# Tree to adjacency matrix python

Tags: python, matrix

Sample representation of a tree V:

```
V = [3, [
        [1, []] ,
        [0, [
            [2, []] ,
            [5, []]]],
        [4, []]]]
```

3 is the root node of the tree and each element within a nested list represents a child of the node. So V is a tree with 3 as the root node, 1, 0, and 4 as the children of 3, and 2 and 5 as the children of 0. 
This is my code so far:

```
def tree_to_matrix_helper(tree, size, matrix):
    for i in range(0, len(tree[1])) :
        matrix[tree[0]][tree[1][i][0]] = 1
        matrix[tree[1][i][0]][tree[0]] = 1
        if len(tree[1][i][1]) > 0:
           tree_to_matrix_helper(tree[1][i], size-len(tree[1])-1, matrix)
    return matrix

def tree_to_matrix(tree, size) :
    matrix_row = []
    matrix = []
    for i in range(0, size):
        matrix_row.append(0)
    for i in range(0, size):
        matrix.append(matrix_row)
    return tree_to_matrix_helper(tree, size, matrix)
```

What's really weird is that when I initialize the matrix with the for loops, I get a 6x6 adjacency matrix of only 1's when I run tree_to_matrix(V,6), which is clearly wrong. But when I initialize matrix simply by saying

```
    matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

(which is the same as the matrix initialized by the for loops)
and then run tree_to_matrix(V,6), I get the proper corresponding adjacency matrix. That'll work for any tree of size 6 of course but I have to abstract this for a tree of any size. Problem is the only way I can think of initializing the adjacency matrix is how I did it in my main function, but for that every single row in the matrix seems to always turns out the same. So how can I perform this abstraction?

Comment: `matrix.append(matrix_row)` appends the *same list object* to `matrix` every time. Every element of `matrix` is the *same object*.

Comment: and to fix that, you could "matrix.append(list(matrix_row))" thus constructing a separate instance of the list. Or minor tip, type "[0] * 6" on the python prompt and see what happens.